# Flash AS2 show text one by one from array

Tags: for-loop, actionscript-2

I want to dynamically display some text from an array one after another in a dynamic textfield.

var wordList:Array = new Array('one','two','three');

for (var i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
    this.text_mc.txt.text = wordlist[i];
    // Pause for 3 seconds and then move next
}

its the "Pause for 3 seconds and then move next" part I cant figure out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

track what index of the array you are currently showing, and use the `setInterval` function to call your 'showNext' function every 3000 milliseconds

ie)

```
var wordList:Array = new Array('one','two','three');
var curIndex = 0;

renderText(curIndex);

setInterval( showNextText, 3000 );

function showNextText()
{
    curIndex++;
    renderText(curIndex);        
}

function renderText( index:Number )
{
    this.text_mc.txt.text = wordlist[index];
}
```